# Java Scanner: I have to entry thrice the same value

Tags: java

if I replace typedNum in if with x
`((typedNum.nextInt() > 21 && typedNum.nextInt()< 30))`, then it works perfectly. Why is that so?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static int number(Scanner typedNum) {
    int x = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 1) {
      x = typedNum.nextInt();
      if ((typedNum.nextInt() > 21 && typedNum.nextInt()< 30)) {
        System.out.println("in range");
        i=1;
      } 
     else {
        System.out.println("Not in range");
      }

    }
    System.out.println(x);
    return (x);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
    number(y);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every instance of a call to `typedNum.nextInt()` takes a separate input from `STDIN`. It works perfectly when you use `x` in the place of the function call because you need to take the input only once and use it multiple times later.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `nextInt()`, scanner will read in a new number. If you do `nextInt() > 21 && nextInt() < 30`, it will read one number, compare it to 21, and if it is less, it will not evaluate the second half of the and. This is called "short-circuit evaluation". If it is more, the second half of the and will be evaluated, and another value will be read. You should instead be comparing `x` each time.

```java
      x = typedNum.nextInt();
      if ((x > 21 && x < 30)) {
        System.out.println("in range");
        i=1;
      }
```